# Ansible conditionals with nested loops

Tags: ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

I've read the ansible docs on conditionals and loops. But it's still not clear to me how it exactly works.

my yaml structure looks like this:

```
---
myusers:
   - username: user1
     homedir: 'home1'
     sshkey: 'ssh-rsa bla1'
   - username: user2
     homedir: 'home2'
     sshkey: 'ssh-rsa bla2'
     process: 
        - transfer:
          transtype: 'curl'
          traname: 'ftps://targetsystem'
```

my playbook part looks like this:

```
   - name: test j2
     debug:
       msg: |-
         dest: "/var/tmp/{{ item.0.username }}/{{ item.1.traname }} {{ item.1.transtype }}"
     when: item.0.process is not none
     loop: "{{ myusers | subelements('process')}}"
```

Now I only want to loop when the sub-element process exists. I had this working at one point but don't understand what I changed to break it.
Mainly I don't understand what the effect of the sequence of 'when' and 'loop' has. It appears to me when I run it that the condition 'when' is ignored. Also when I swap the sequence of when and loop.

The error I get when running the playbook is :

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "could not find 'process' key in iterated item {u'username': u'user1' ...
```

I've also tried with different conditions like:

```
 item.0.process is defined
 myusers.username.process is not none
```

etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel//collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html) (and the corresponding [lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html)) requires each top level element to have the subelement key (and will error with the above message if it does not exist)

You can change this behavior by setting the [`skip_missing` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#parameter-skip_missing) (note: I also fixed the index to address the `traname` key which was the wrong one in your question example)

```yaml
   - name: test j2
     debug:
       msg: |-
         dest: "/var/tmp/{{ item.0.username }}/{{ item.1.traname }} {{ item.1.transtype }}"
     loop: "{{ myusers | subelements('process', skip_missing=true) }}"
```